# Why do I get a "Too many input arguments" error when not passing any?

Tags: function, matlab, parameters, arguments

I am working on some simple object-oriented code in MATLAB. I am trying to call one of my class methods with no input or output arguments in its definition.

Function definition:

`function roll_dice`

Function call:

`obj.roll_dice;`

When this is executed, MATLAB says:

```
??? Error using ==> roll_dice
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> DiceSet>Diceset.Diceset at 11
obj.roll_dice;
(etc...)
```

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing it? Are there secret automatic arguments I'm unaware that I'm passing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you make the call:

```
obj.roll_dice;
```

It is actually equivalent to:

```
roll_dice(obj);
```

So `obj` is the "secret" automatic argument being passed to `roll_dice`. If you rewrite the method `roll_dice` to accept a single input argument (even if you don't use it), things should work correctly.

Alternatively, if you know for sure that your method `roll_dice` is not going to perform any operations on the class object, you can declare it to be a [static method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brdqiu3.html) as [Dan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715624/matlab-too-many-input-arguments-when-not-passing-any/735905#735905).

For more information on object-oriented programming in MATLAB, [here's a link to the online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html).

Comment: Ie, roll_dict is being called as a method on an object when it shouldn't be.  Try roll_dice() instead of obj.roll_dice().

Comment: That might work, but he did say roll_dice is a class method, so I'm guessing it's intended to operate on a given object.

Comment: You were right, but now I have a different problem.  I'm coming from languages like Java and PHP where it is fairly straightforward to use classes.  What is the equivalent of self.roll_dice or this.roll_dice?

Comment: Most class methods I've seen are written to accept the object being operated on as the first argument. This first argument can be thought of as a "self" reference. I suggest this MATLAB documentation link for help:  http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can also get around this by declaring roll_dice to be a static method.

Comment: +1: Yes, if roll_dice is a static method then obj.roll_dice should work without needing to add any input arguments to the function definition.